# Scripting Cocoa application property

Tags: cocoa, properties, applescript

I have a property of my application in my sdef dictionary called `busy`

```
<property name="busy" code="mybs" type="boolean" access="r" description="Is application busy?">
    <cocoa key="isBusy"/>
</property>
```

Also I have NSApplication category with `isBusy` accessor

```
- (BOOL)isBusy
{
    return NO;
}
```

The scripts

```
tell application "MyApplication"
    properties
end tell
```

and

```
tell application "MyApplication"
    busy
end tell
```

work fine and `busy` property is false, but script

```
busy of application "MyApplication"
```

returns error

```
error "MyApplication got an error: Can’t make |busy| into type specifier." number -1700 from |busy| to specifier
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but sometimes with commands you need to explicitly use "get". I assume it's just an applescript quirk when this happens. So does "get busy of..." work?

Comment: No, the same error as without `get`

Comment: If you want a one line alternative: `tell application "MyApplication" to get busy.` Just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `busy` is a term specific to your application, it must be preceded by `tell` or `using terms from` to make the term known at that point in the code. Any of these will work:

```
tell application "MyApplication" to busy

tell application "MyApplication"
  busy
end tell

using terms from application "MyApplication"
  busy of application "MyApplication"
end using terms from
```

AppleScript parses left-to-right and has to know what the valid terms are before it can parse them. It doesn’t skip to the end of `busy of application "MyApplication"` to figure out how to parse the start of the expression. If MyApplication had a term `busy of` it would completely change the meaning of that expression and cause a paradox: `of` would no longer be the keyword used to construct object specifiers, which means it wouldn’t get terminology from MyApplication, which means it *would* be the `of` keyword and it *would* get the terminology from the application…ad infinitum.

You may be wondering why some application properties, like `name`, `version` and `running` work without introducing the application’s terminology. They work because they’re defined by the global system terminology and are not specific to your application.

Note that the `'s` possessive operator does *not* introduce terminology like `tell` does, so this doesn’t work, either (unless you precede it with a `tell` or `using terms from`):

```
application "MyApplication"'s busy
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because it is an illegal Apple Script sentence. 
The `get` command, which was suggested by regulus6633, will prepended automatically if you omit it (See Events tab in Apple Script Editor). And each command needs a performer to execute it. The implied `get` command has in your broken sentence no container which is necessary to build a specifier like "blah of blah of blah"t